# My app on ipad looks bigger

Tags: ios, ipad, react-native

I developed a React Native application and i was able to deploy it on different Android devices. I also did it on I Phones and everything works as expected
But When i am trying to deploy it on I Pad, the application looks like a normal mobile app. I mean all the components are bigger. It's like a mobile with zoom.

Does the deploy on I Pad differs from the other devices?
Do i have to set something in X Code in the moment i deploy the application?

Do you have any idea what i do wrong or what i have to set?

Comment: I think it will be as what you have experienced only. How do you expect the app to be?

Comment: When i deploy it on an Android tablet it looks good. All the components have the same size as on a mobile device with more space between them. On an IPad instead all of them are bigger like all the components were stretched or zoomed

Comment: If you want to support the iPad natively then you need to make sure your project is set as universal in Xcode. If you set it to iPhone only then it runs at 3.5" resolution on an ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone only apps run in a zoomed mode on iPad. Set the `Devices` to `Universal` under Target > Deployment Info. This will allow your app to run on iPhone and iPad in full resolution. You may need to adjust your layouts if they are not setup to stretch with the larger screen size.

[image: devices menu]

Answer (score 0):

in react-native version 0.72.X and Xcode v15
you should add ipad iten into "Supported Destinations" section

[image]

and add this items into "info.plist" in ios folder
[image]